# Why does this 'hello world' x86 bootloader code written for NASM work without the [BITS 16] and [ORG 0x7C00] directives?

Tags: x86, nasm, assembly, bootloader

```
push word 0b800h
pop es
xor di, di
mov [es:di], word 441h
jmp $
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
db 55h
db 0AAh
```

Comment: Bootloader code has to be 16bit code IIRC (on x86 PC platform)

Comment: The code does not reference labels/addresses for ORG to matter. (Just guessing) 16-bit instruction are default?

Comment: wqw answer is the correct one. You're only using CPU instructions, and you have no addressable label in your file.
16 bits is the default for flat-binaries. For other kind of output, it's 32 bits.

Answer (score 10):

Because you are writing a flat binary without labels. NASM should default to 16-bit. Related to this is the fact that you have no addressing or labels - so no requirement to provide an [ORG ...] directive.